# Retrieve first row from 1 to n matrix and second row from n+1th matrix to n+nth matrix

Tags: matlab

I have 1028 (7*21) matrix, and i saved these 1028 different matrix in a single array. lets say the array be a , so 
             a[1] contain first matrix
             a[2] contain second matrix
             a[3] contain third matrix 
             a[4] contain fourth matrix and so on 
             ...
             ... 
            a[1028] contain 1028th matrix.

Now i want to retrieve 1 to 147th matrix first row ,  148 to 294th matrix second row ,295 to 441th matrix third row and so on upto 1028.

Comment: Are you sure you have 1028 matrices and not **7*147=1029** matrices?

Comment: if the answer helped you, please mark it as "accepted" (the check on the left) - so the system knows the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

After some preparations you can use `reshape`.

```
% generate example data
X = {repmat({rand(7,21)},1028,1)}
```

which is a `1028x1 cell` - but you need **1029** matrices do make it divisible by **147**:

```
X = vertcat(X{1},{[]})
```

now you can reshape it as desired:

```
Y = reshape(X,147,[])
```

which is a `147x7 cell` with 1028 of your `7x21` matrices and one empty placeholder.

---

A more generic solution for an arbitrary number of elements of `X` and a chosen **divisor** would be:

```
divisor = 147;

N = numel( X{1} );                                     %// for example 1023
missingCells = ceil(N/divisor)*divisor - N;            %// would be 6 then
X = vertcat( X{1}, repmat({[]}, missingCells,1) );     %// fill up with + 6 cells
Y = reshape( X, divisor,[] );                          %// 147x7 cell
```